# How to get output for each input after 5 layers of conv1d

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am implementing a 5 layer Conv1D for my data which has the shape:

```
(10000,160,1)
```

the input shape for my conv1d model is :

```
(None,160,1)
```

I am trying to obtain the output of the flattened layer (whose output is (none,8000) in the figure below)

My model looks like this:
[image]

The way I understand the working of Conv1D, at each time, (batch_size,160,1) input goes in, and should give me a (batch size,8000) output right? so if my model is seeing (10000,160,1) of total data, at the e end of extracting output, I should get (10000, 8000).

The code I use to get the output of the flatten layer is:

```
layer = 'flatten'
extractor = Model(inputs=ecg_input,outputs=[layer.output for layer in model.layers])
layer_output = extractor(data)
```

I am not getting the desired output as I am getting a list of length 50 instead of required output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `extractor`'s output is a list containing the outputs of each and every single layer in your model, that is, `conv_input1`'s output, `conv_1d_1`'s output, `conv_1d_2`'s output ... (in that order).

You need to either find the index of the output tensor of `flatten` layer in the list to extract it, or simply set the `extractor`'s output as `flatten`'s output in the first place.

```
extractor = Model(inputs=ecg_input,outputs=model.get_layer('flatten').output)
```

Comment: hey @bui thanks for the help. I am doing exactly what you showed here. I am still confused as I am getting a list of length 50. should I get a list of length = my input data?

Comment: What do you mean by "list"? Do you mean a tensor, or a Python list because if you've done like my suggestion, you should not get a Python list at all.

Comment: Hey do you know how can I extract the last layer output from loading a saved model with a new dataset?